# Coding challenge, struggling to figure out how to return a string from a method

Tags: javascript

I am working through a code challenge and I need to return a string into a variable if the guess passed in `attemptAnswer(guess)` matches the `answer` property's value. My test is failing currently saying that the variable `response` is undefined.

Is this some sort of binding issue?

...curious how this problem could be resolved.

Thank you!

```
class Sphinx {
    constructor() {
        this.name = null;
        this.riddles = [];
    }
    collectRiddle(riddle) {
        this.riddles.push(riddle);
        if (this.riddles.length > 3) { this.riddles.shift() };
    }
    attemptAnswer(guess) {
        this.riddles.forEach( (element, index) => {
            if (guess === element.answer) { 
                this.riddles.splice(index, 1);
                return "That wasn't that hard, I bet you don't get the next one."
            };
        })
    }
}

//test
 const response = sphinx.attemptAnswer('short');
 assert.equal(response, 'That wasn\'t that hard, I bet you don\'t get the next one');
```

Comment: You have another problem with your code. You `splice()` in the middle of a `forEach()` loop which will cause iteration to skip the entry after the removed index in the `riddles` array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you return in `attemptAnswer()` you're actually retuning to the inner `forEach` callback function you defined: `(element, index) => {...`, not the outer `attemptAnswer()` method.

Instead of immediately returning within your `forEach` loop, you can set a variable outside this loop called `result`, and then return the `result` once your `forEach` loop is complete.

Also, currently, you're not creating a new instance of `Sphinx`, which means you don't have an object which can call the `attemptAnswer()` method. To fix this add `new Sphinx()` to create a new `Sphinx` object.

See example below:

```js
class Sphinx {
  constructor() {
    this.name = null;
    this.riddles = [{"answer":"short"}];
  }
  collectRiddle(riddle) {
    this.riddles.push(riddle);
    if (this.riddles.length > 3) {
      this.riddles.shift()
    };
  }
  attemptAnswer(guess) {
    let res = "";
    this.riddles.forEach((element, index) => {
      if (guess === element.answer && !res) { 
        // no need for splice as it will skip an entry
        res = "That wasn't that hard, I bet you don't get the next one.";
      };
    })
    return res;
  }
}


const response = new Sphinx();
response.collectRiddle({"answer":"short"});
console.log(response.attemptAnswer('short'));
```

Answer (score 0):

you're never calling `collectRiddle` so `this.riddles` is always `[]` and the `forEach` block is never entered, therefore, not returning anything, so, the return value is `undefined`

you should have a variable called `found` right before the loop, if you find a match, set it to `true`then return the string depending on the `found` variable :

note : the string inside the function is different from the one you're comparing it to (it has backslashes and ends with a dot) so the test will always be falsy

```js
class Sphinx {
  constructor() {
    this.name = null;
    this.riddles = [];
  }
  collectRiddle(riddle) {
    this.riddles.push(riddle);
    if (this.riddles.length > 3) {
      this.riddles.shift()
    };
  }
  attemptAnswer(guess) {
    var found = false;
    this.riddles.forEach((element, index) => {

      if (guess === element.answer) {
        found = true;
      }
    })
    return found ? "Woohoo" : "That wasn't that hard, I bet you don't get the next one."
  }
}

//test
const s = new Sphinx();
const response = s.attemptAnswer('short');

console.log(response === `That wasn't that hard, I bet you don't get the next one.`);
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you already did `const sphynx = new Sphynx()`.

`attemptAnswer()` doesn't return anything, in Javascript, if you don't return anything, you basically return `undefined`. So it is normal that response is undefined.

In your case, I would use **for-loop**, instead of **forEach**.

```
attemptAnswer(guess) {
  for (let i = 0; i < this.riddles.length; i++) {
    if (guess === this.riddles[i].answer) {
      this.riddles.splice(index, 1);
      return "That wasn't that hard, I bet you don't get the next one.";
    }
  }
  return "Not found";
}
```

*Using `.splice()` inside forEach is not recommended*

*using forEach, will go through all the items inside the array, even if you already found your answer.*